# Delay boot after all services UBUNTU

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I wonder if there is any way to delay the ubuntu-desktop screen. My application runs on Ubuntu 20.04 I have a docker service that starts right away, but the containers come with a delay. I would like to arrange it like this: Turn on the computer --> All the services are running --> delay for 60sec while I see black screen with UBUNTU start up logo

If anyone has experience with it I would appreciate the help.

Thank you!

Comment: Exactly what do you want delayed, the prompt to log in or something else?

Comment: Yes exactly, the goal is to delay the screen before the login (it works with automatic login). The computer will boot with all the systems services and only after that *before the login page* I would like to add a delay